Отключить горячие клавиши electron'а по умолчанию
Я хотел сделать изменение масштаба в своем Electron приложении.
Но, Electron имеет две комбинации, которые работают не так как мне надо:

ctrl + shift + =
ctrl + -

(клавиши возле backspace, не на nampad'е)
Как я могу их отключить?
globalShortcut.unregisterAll() не помогли

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/global-shortcut#globalshortcutunregisterall

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/global-shortcut#globalshortcutregisteraccelerator-callback
